# Floating an icon via CSS

Tags: css

I am working on a webpage that uses Bootstrap. My page looks like this:

```
+----------------------------------------+
| Hello                                  |
+----------------------------------------+
| This is some text.                     |
| This part of the page                  |
| is contained in a                      |
| col-md-6. This                [icon]   |
| content will be long                   |
| and should be allowed                  |
| to scroll. However,                    |
|+---------------------------------------+
```

I am trying to make it so the `[icon]` floats, vertically, in the middle. When the user scrolls down the page, I want the `[icon]` to stay in place. My question is how do I do that? I have the `[icon]` horizontally centered using the following code:

```
<div class="col-md-6" style="text-align:center;">
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>    
</div>
```

However, there are two problems:

1. Its not vertically centered
2. When a user scrolls down the page, the icon scrolls off the page. It does not stay fixed in place.

I appreciate any help that's available.

Comment: Your 2nd issue cannot be solved with pure css. You will need to use a javascript like [Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/). CSS has no idea when you scroll to toggle something to be fixed or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make `fixed` your icon side and center the icon using `flexbox`.

[In this pen](http://codepen.io/elrumordelaluz/pen/0a34d4892205d77472efd0aaea625a3c?editors=1100) there's a possible solution.

Comment: Wow! That's cool. I didn't know about the vw and vh units. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

The bootstrap 'Media' component will do that.  Looks like you want `media-right media-middle` for what you are trying to do here.  Just put `<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>` in place of the image.

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#media

Fixing the icon in place when you scroll is a different thing altogether...you would either need to fix the position from the start (which might be a problem if the content you are aligning it to changes) or detect a scroll event with JS and position it fixed at that time.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you're not using bootstrap, you could create the media object yourself.

Harry Roberts calls the thing bootstrap does internally a flag object, because the display type changes internally when you use `.media-middle`

http://csswizardry.com/2013/05/the-flag-object/